# Android RotationSensor returns positive values but no negative values ? on y axis

Tags: android, vector, rotation, onchange, android-sensors

I need help with onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event). I can get a toast message when device is facedown (y axis)  0 to 180.but can not get it to work going the other way on the (y axis) -0 to -180 faceup. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your interest,

Mike

Relevant code follows:

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mRotationSensor;
private double[] values;
private String TAG;

private static final int SENSOR_DELAY = 500 * 1000; // 500ms
private static final int FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS = -57;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mRotationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationSensor, SENSOR_DELAY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hardware compatibility issue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor == mRotationSensor) {
        if (event.values.length > 4) {
            float[] truncatedRotationVector = new float[4];
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, truncatedRotationVector, 0, 4);
            update(truncatedRotationVector);
        } else {
             update(event.values);
        }
    }
}

private void update(float[] vectors) {
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, vectors);
    int worldAxisX = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
    int worldAxisZ = SensorManager.AXIS_Z;
    float[] adjustedRotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, worldAxisX, worldAxisZ, adjustedRotationMatrix);
    float[] orientation = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedRotationMatrix, orientation);
    float pitch = orientation[1] * FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS;
    float roll = orientation[2] * FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS;
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.pitch)).setText("Pitch: "+pitch);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.roll)).setText("Roll: "+roll);


    if (pitch    <= 81 && pitch    >= 50) {
        // mostly vertical
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device Face Down ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    {

       if (pitch   < -81&& pitch    >= -50) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device Face Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





        }} }
```

Comment: Update to help request:

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,but the values are not expressed as I stated when the questions was asked,but are as follows:onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event). I can get a toast message when device is facedown (y axis) 0 to 89 then 89 to 0 again.but can not get it to work going the other way on the (y axis) -0 to -89 then -89 to- 0  again  faceup.